# Which widget in PySide is similar to wxNotebook control in wxwidgets?

Tags: wxpython, pyside, wxnotebook

I have to replace the wxNotebook control with a PySide equivalent. Which widget/approach in PySide shall I use best?

Comment: If it helps in any way, the wxNotebook is a container that holds multiple panels as tabs.

Comment: @user2963623 Thanks, does it mean if I use pyside, I can use WidgetTab to get the same output?

Comment: I am not familiar with pyqt4/pyside widgets, but seeing the examples on internet, I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a tab widget in pyside/ pyqt4 which is similar to a notebook in wxwidgets:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore
import sys

def main():

    app     = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tabs    = QtGui.QTabWidget()
    pushButton1 = QtGui.QPushButton("QPushButton 1")
    pushButton2 = QtGui.QPushButton("QPushButton 2")

    tab1    = QtGui.QWidget()   
    tab2    = QtGui.QWidget()
    tab3    = QtGui.QWidget()

    vBoxlayout  = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton1)
    vBoxlayout.addWidget(pushButton2)

    #Resize width and height
    tabs.resize(250, 150)

    #Move QTabWidget to x:300,y:300
    tabs.move(300, 300)

    #Set Layout for Third Tab Page
    tab3.setLayout(vBoxlayout)   

    tabs.addTab(tab1,"Tab 1")
    tabs.addTab(tab2,"Tab 2")
    tabs.addTab(tab3,"Tab 3")

    tabs.setWindowTitle('PyQt QTabWidget Add Tabs and Widgets Inside Tab')
    tabs.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Courtesy of [This](http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?index=356&key=QTabWidgetAddTabandWidgets)